# How to shutdown multiple PCs in a domain with PowerShell reading a txt

Tags: powershell

How can I shutdown multiple PCs in a domain reading a txt file and not those in the file. I tried like this but doesn't work.

```
function ShutdownFile4 {
    Param(
        [switch]$showErrors
    )
    ([adsisearcher]"objectcategory=computer").FindAll() | ForEach-Object {
        try {
            Test-Connection -ComputerName ([adsi]$_.Path).Cn -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -TimeToLive 1 -EA Stop
            if ($Computers = gc "C:\.....ElencoPC.txt") {
                foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
                }
            } else {
                foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
                    Stop-Computer -ComputerName ([adsi]$_.Path).Cn
                }
            }
        } catch [System.Exception] {
            if ($showErrors) {
                $error[0].ToString()-00.
            }
        }
    }
}

ShutdownFile4 -showErrors
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read the computer list into a variable and only try to shutdown computers from that list if the read is *not* successful.

Read the list *before* you search AD for computers, then filter the output of the search for computers matching entries from that list, then check if those are accessible, then shutdown those that are accessible.

```
$Computers = Get-Content 'C:\...\ElencoPC.txt'
([adsisearcher]"objectcategory=computer").FindAll() | Where-Object {
    $Computers -contains ([adsi]$_.Path).Cn
} | ForEach-Object {
    $computer = ([adsi]$_.Path).Cn
    if (Test-Connection -Computer $computer -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        Stop-Computer -Computer $computer
    } else {
        if ($showErrors) {
            "Host unreachable: ${computer}"
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `-contains` is a slow operation, since it does a linear search on an array. You can speed up the comparison by using hashtable lookups if performance becomes an issue.

```
$Computers = @{}
Get-Content 'C:\...\ElencoPC.txt' | ForEach-Object { $Computers[$_] = $true }
([adsisearcher]"objectcategory=computer").FindAll() | Where-Object {
    $Computers.ContainsKey(([adsi]$_.Path).Cn)
} | ...
```

Comment: Also be very careful about using "-TimeToLive 1" - be sure that's really what you need....

Comment: @Scepticalist True. I just copy/pasted that from the question, but presumably `-Count 1 -Quiet` should suffice. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you I didn't explain well I wanted to shutdown the Pc that are not on the list so I change contains with -notcontains, how can I do that with Hashtable also? Than I added -Force after stop-computer because It says The Pc to shutdown was in use and it blocks. And then Windows Firewall block it can I disable it through powershell or gpo or there are other ways?

Comment: @user12363239 `-not $Computers.ContainsKey(...)`. Windows firewall is a different question entirely, which should be asked on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). Personally I'm of the mind that the Windows firewall causes more issues than it solves outside roadwarrior scenarios, so I usually disable it entirely and leave firewalling to the perimeter firewall.